# General equations of the young's two slit experiment

Tags: waves, double-slit-experiment

I'm familiar with the equations from the young's two slit experiment (minimal/maximal conditions and so on). In the experiment, light is located at the middle of the two slits.

Do more general equations exist for light that is placed anywhere between the two slits (it does not have to be in the middle)? For example, the light source could be at the same level as the bottom slit.

I tried to build the equation but it became really complicated.

Comment: You are looking for a solution that is less general than Maxwell's equations for the electromagnetic field?

Comment: Maybe of help. http://web.mit.edu/8.02t/www/802TEAL3D/visualizations/coursenotes/modules/guide14.pdf

Comment: yes , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywcrHu_1Y24 this has two lecture , although a general formula has not been derieved but it has been explained how to deal with such problems

Answer (score 0):

Say we have slit 1 at (0,0) and slit 2 at (s,0).  Say we are trying to find the amplitude of the equation of the light at (x,y), where y is the distance from slit to screen.

Add the wave equations of the light rays. The equations are the same except for the offset because of the differing distances, but similar source amplitude and wavelengths. Find the offsets by finding the remainder of $\frac{sqrt((x-0)^2+(y-0)^2)}{\lambda}$ and $\frac{sqrt((x-s)^2+(y-0)^2)}{\lambda}$.  Take those offsets and insert them into the combined equation for the light at that point, $y=Asin(\frac{2π}{\lambda}(x+\phi_1))+Asin(\frac{2π}{\lambda}(x+\phi_2))$ where A is the maximum amplitude of the source light and $\phi$ is the offset.  Because you can think of the position of the beam as the time it will take for that part of the beam to hit the screen point, this equation models the light as a function of time as well as distance in terms of the amplitude. The resultant amplitude y of that equation is the amplitude you see.  Thus, the expression you are looking for is

$ Asin(\frac{2π}{\lambda}(x+(sqrt((x-0)^2+(y-0)^2) % \lambda )))+Asin(\frac{2π}{\lambda}(x+(\frac{sqrt((x-s)^2+(y-0)^2)%\lambda))) $